# PHP htmlentities Double Encoding

Tags: php, sql, oracle, wysiwyg, html-entities

I'm trying to save the contents of a **WYSIWYG** input into an Oracle database. Here's what I'm using:

```
$data = htmlentities($_POST['data'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

My expectation is that when I'm going to put `John's` as the value for the input, it will be saved on the database as `John&#39;s`, but instead it is being saved as `John&amp;#39;`.

To me it looks like a double HTML entity encoding issue.

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: i suspect it's oracle escaping characters, however, to make sure try to `var_dump($data)` (also, `var_dump($_POST['data'])`) and  look for it's output to be sure.

Comment: Maybe the WYSIWYG is converting it once? Why do you need to encode `'`s to their entity, hopefully not to avoid SQL injections?

Comment: @chris85 What's the general practice in saving the contents of a WYSIWYG input?

Comment: It depends what the WYSIWYG is set up to send and how you are going to use that output later. Your user input shouldn't go directly into a SQL query though.

Comment: @chris85 I at least know that part that's why I'm using `htmlentities`. The only reason why I'm trying to escape  `'` is because on my query I use single quotes to denote strings.

Comment: Use parameterized queries; or use an already defined escaping function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing through the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), I noticed that the last parameter is a boolean for double encoding.

```
$data = htmlentities($_POST['data'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", false);
```

did the trick.